# How can I deploy my web application to a remote IIS server that doesn't have the wwwroot folder shared on the network?

Tags: iis, jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins, web-deployment

I'm trying to move into continuous integration.  To accomplish this, I'd need to be able to publish to the wwwroot folder of our IIS server.  However, the IIS server doesn't have any of its folders shared out onto our network.  That said, I'm not quite sure how to get my build to that machine.  Normally, I'd zip my web app folder, ftp it over to the ftproot folder, backup the current version of my web application, then unzip my web application to the appropriate folder on wwwroot.  So, given that I have the login/password to remote desktop to the machine and ftp access to ftproot, does anyone know how I might get my files to the wwwroot folder without the sysadmins having to share out the wwwroot folder?  I was hoping there was some RDP command I could use to send files over, but I know it's not that simple.  I'm currently using Jenkins to auto-build.  Now I just have to figure out the deployment part.  Any and all suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

If you have admin permissions on the remote box, there are always the hidden shares `C$`, `D$`, etc. They give access to the whole drive. There is also a chance that system admins may have disabled that.

`\\rem.ip.address\C$\wwwroot`

Answer (score 0):

You could try using Microsoft Web Deploy or a tool like Puppet. Another option is publishing your web application to an Artifact Repository like Nexus or Artifactory and then downloading it from the repository to the server using remote powershell commands.